# List visible pivot items with Excel formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

In an Excel pivot table, when I select multiple items in a report filter, Excel just displays that I have selected multiple items.

Data

[image: Data]

I can select multiple items:

[image: Pivot2]

However, once the selection is done, I don't see which elements I have selected.

[image: Pivot1]

I want to display which items are selected, e.g. when the report is printed. I found a way to do this using VBA and a user defined function.

```
Function GetVisibleItems(FieldName As String) As String

    Dim PivotTable As PivotTable
    Set PivotTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)

    Dim PivotField As PivotField
    Set PivotField = PivotTable.PivotFields(FieldName)

    Dim PivotItem As PivotItem
    Dim Result As String

    For Each PivotItem In PivotField.PivotItems()
        If PivotItem.Name <> "(blank)" Then
            If PivotItem.Visible Then
                If Len(Result) > 0 Then Result = Result & ", "
                Result = Result & PivotItem.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next

    GetVisibleItems = Result

End Function
```

Is it possible to get the same result using just Excel formulae, not VBA?

Comment: I've read your question several times, and I keep coming back to - in Excel, you can see which items are visible! I think we need a little context - what would you use a cell containing list of visible items for?

Comment: You can see which items are visible when you click on the field. But when you print out the sheet you no longer can see the selection on which the report is based. That's why I want to see the actual selection in a separate field. If I can do this in pure Excel, I don't have to distribute an `.xlsm`-file.

Comment: Can you mock up a simple example of what you are looking for? I tried to provide an answer, but I think I am missing something in your question.

Comment: I just realized that Excel has a solution for my problem. No formula necessary. Just use slicers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for is provided by [Slicers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-slicers-to-filter-PivotTable-data-249F966B-A9D5-4B0F-B31A-12651785D29D). A slicer shows the range that has been selected and is printable. Writing the list of visible Pivot Elements into a cell is possible, maybe even with a tricky Excel formula, but seems like over-engineering it.

Answer (score 0):

Martin - This probably isn't as straight forward as you are looking for, but using workbook functions to build the string you are looking for ...

Below is a simple table of information ...

[image]

... and a pivot table created from it ...

[image]

In the pivot, you can see that Person 2 and Person 6 are filtered out.

Back at the table, a column was added using this formula (filled down) ...

`=IF(ISERROR(GETPIVOTDATA("Grade",Sheet5!$A$3,$A$1,A2)),"",A2)`

Note: Sheet5 contains the Pivot table. A3 is the top left corner of the pivot.

Providing this result ...

[image]

Where there are blanks instead of Person 2 and Person 6.

The string was generated using [Chip Pearson's StringConcat UDF](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/stringconcatenation.aspx) because it's more compact than all the typing needed with `&` or `CONCATENATE` ...

[image]

Comment: Well, I would still need VBA for the UDF.

Answer (score 0):

The [TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function can do this.  Excel 2016 onwards.

> The TEXTJOIN function combines the text from multiple ranges and/or strings, and includes a delimiter you specify between each text value that will be combined. If the delimiter is an empty text string, this function will effectively concatenate the ranges.